# Clang issues -Wunused-value depending on whether the code is called from a macro

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I use a special assertion macros called `CHECK`. It is implemented like this:

```c++
#define CHECK(condition)  check(condition).ok ? std::cerr : std::cerr
```

The user can choose to provide additional information that is printed if the assertion fails:

```c++
CHECK(a.ok());
CHECK(a.ok()) << a.to_string();
```

Notice the ternary operator in macro definition. It ensures that `a.to_string()` is executed only when the assertion fails. So far so good. I've been using this (and other similar) macros for a long time without any problems.

But recently I found that clang issues “expression result unused [-Wunused-value]” warning regarding the second `std::cerr` if `CHECK` is used inside another macro:

```c++
#define DO(code)  do { code } while(0)

int main() {
    do { CHECK(2 * 2 == 4); } while(0);  // no warning
    DO( CHECK(2 * 2 == 4); );  // warning
}
```

Full example: https://godbolt.org/z/5bfnEGqsn.

This makes no sense to me. Why would this diagnostic depend on whether the code was expanded from a macro or not? GCC issues no warnings in either case.

Two questions:

- Is there any reason for such behavior or should I file this as clang bug?
- How can I suppress this without disabling “-Wunused-value” altogether? I've tried `[[maybe_unused]]` and `__attribute__((unused))` but they don't seem to work on statements.

Comment: Your macro is flawed, as `<<` has higher precedence than the conditional operator. So `CHECK(a.ok()) << a.to_string();` will expand to (essentially) `check(a.ok()).ok ? std::cerr : (std::cerr << a.to_string());` This is one of the biggest failures of macros.

Comment: And if you use `CHECK(a.ok());` then you indeed have an unused value, as the result of the conditional expression is unused and ignored.

Comment: Some programmer dude, the macro is not flawed. `check(a.ok()).ok ? std::cerr : (std::cerr << a.to_string());` is how the macro is _supposed_ to expand. Together with the fact that the false branch of ternary operation is not executed this allows to avoid evaluating (potentially expensive) `a.to_string()` when the assertion passes.

Comment: Some programmer dude, my question is not about why this warning would trigger at all. The question is why does the fact that the warning triggers depends on whether `CHECK` is used inside a macros or not. And how to suppress it.

Comment: BTW: As c++ defines a lot of consteval/constexpr stuff, why we have macros in in use like in the 70ths ? I know, it is totally unrelated to the question, but seeing this macro things again and again looks outdated for me.

Comment: Klaus, the reason this is a macro is because the full implementation prints code location (file, line) and arguments as strings. E.g. with my actual assertion suit I could do stuff like `CHECK_EQ(a, b)` and it would automatically produce message like: “assertion failed at foo.cpp:167: a == b a.k.a. 2 == 3”. I know that C++20 added `std::source_location`, but I'm using C++17 for now; plus, it's still impossible to print the arguments without macros.

Comment: `The question is why does the fact that the warning triggers depends on whether CHECK is used inside a macros or not.`  likely to be a bug that clang misses that the expression result is unused when a macro is involved (that depends on when they do that check and how/when they expand macros). So you can file a bug report that they also should detect that when macros are used.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the preprocessed output from the second program to see if anything differs between the explicit `do while` loop compared to the one from the `DO` macro. Either way I would still expect a warning since if the `true` branch is taken then the result will be unused.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the preprocessor output (`-E`)  shown for the godbolt link results in `do { check(2 * 2 == 4).ok ? std::cerr : std::cerr; } while(0);` for both cases and `do { check(2 * 2 == 4).ok ? std::cerr : std::cerr; } while(0);` alone without any macro also results in that `expression result unused` error. So it seems pretty clear to me that using macros to some prevents the compiler to detect that problem to some degree.

Comment: Do you really need the syntax to be `CHECK(a.ok()) << a.to_string();` instead of having something like `CHECK(a.ok, [&a](auto err) => { err << a.to_string();} )`?

Comment: @t.niese, this is a valid point. The only reason not to use a lambda here is brevity. I do value brevity though. I understand that there are legit concerns regarding my solution, e.g. the one that you pointed out in your answer. I still find lambda clumsiness to be the bigger problem.

Comment: @AndreiMatveiakin I updated my answer with another solution. I still don't like that due to the reason I mention it in my answer. I generally have problems with `assert` like constructs, for which it isn't obvious at the first look whether something is executed or not. I more than once encountered problems in code where something was expected to be executed but didn't due to that. So I prefer a clumsiness solution over a short one to prevent that kind of stuff. But in the end, it is your design decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is a good solution what I suggest here but you could change your code so that you will always use your `std::cerr`, by changing your `check(condition).ok ? std::cerr : std::cerr` to `check(condition).ok ? std::cerr << "" : std::cerr << ""`:

```
#include <iostream>


struct CheckResult {
    CheckResult(bool ok_arg) : ok(ok_arg) {}
    ~CheckResult() { if (!ok) abort(); }
    bool ok;
};

inline CheckResult check(bool ok) {
    if (!ok) std::cerr << "Assertion failed!\n";
    return CheckResult(ok);
}

#define CHECK(condition)  \
    check(condition).ok ? std::cerr << "" : std::cerr << ""

#define DO(code)  \
    do { code } while(0)


int main() {
    do { CHECK(2 * 2 == 4); } while(0);
    DO( CHECK(2 * 2 == 4); );
}
```

Another thing you could do is to use a function that returns that `std::cerr`:

```
#include <iostream>


struct CheckResult {
    CheckResult(bool ok_arg) : ok(ok_arg) {}
    ~CheckResult() { if (!ok) abort(); }
    bool ok;
};

inline CheckResult check(bool ok) {
    if (!ok) std::cerr << "Assertion failed!\n";
    return CheckResult(ok);
}

[[maybe_unused]] inline std::ostream & get_ostream() {
    return std::cerr;
}

#define CHECK(condition)  \
    check(condition).ok ? get_ostream() : get_ostream()

#define DO(code)  \
    do { code } while(0)


int main() {
    do { CHECK(2 * 2 == 4); } while(0);
    DO( CHECK(2 * 2 == 4); );
}
```

The `[[maybe_unused]]` here is not about the returned value but about the function in case that you change your code so that it is not used under certain conditions (maybe not needed here).

My major concern about your approach is this statement:

> Notice the ternary operator in macro definition. It ensures that `a.to_string()` is executed only when the assertion fails.

Without reading the documentation and just looking at `CHECK(a.ok()) << a.to_string();` on one would assume that `a.to_string()` will only be executed if the assertion fails.

For a standpoint of code review or collaboration, this can be really problematic.